# Extra argument 'completion' in call

Tags: swift

New to coding and keep getting the above error on the line "Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: emailField, password: passwordField, completion: { (user, error) in". I have no idea what's wrong and any advice would help thanks.

```
  @IBAction func createAccount (_ sender: AnyObject) {
    Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: emailField, password: passwordField, completion: { (user, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print("Can't Create User")
        } else {
            if let user = user {
                self.userUid = user.user.uid
        }
        }
        self.uploadImg()
    }) {
```

Comment: replace `, completion:` with `)`

Comment: There are several extra braces in your code.

Comment: It's caused by the extra { on the last line. The compiler is expecting this to introduce a trailing closure, but you have already included the argument completion:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had an extra argument in your method's signature and some erroneous braces.

```
@IBAction func createAccount (_ sender: AnyObject) {
    Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: emailField, password: passwordField) { (user, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print("Can't Create User")
        } else {
            if let user = user {
                self.userUid = user.user.uid
            }
        }
        self.uploadImg()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you're seeing is due to syntax errors in your code.

It looks like you may be trying to use [Closures](https://www.aidanf.net/learn-swift/functions#uid90) in your code, but they aren't quite in the form they need to be: `{ (params) -> return_type in statements }`

Without seeing more of the code it's difficult to pin down what you actually want, but with a trailing closure it should look more like this:

```
@IBAction func createAccount (_ sender: AnyObject) {
    Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: emailField, password: passwordField) {
        (user, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print("Can't Create User")
        } else {
            if let user = user {
                self.userUid = user.user.uid
            }
        }
        self.uploadImg()
    }
}
```